# How to find a word matching the first string in a file consisting of words that are space separated in python?

Tags: python, file, search

Let me explain my question better!
I have an input file that is of this format

```
word1 word2  
word3 word4 word5  
word4 word6
```

Given word3, I would like to be able to get the entire row and obtain word4 and word5.

Opening the file, parsing for each line is possible, But my file size is huge and it takes a very long time.
Is there a cost-efficient way in which this can be done?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Quick question: Are you saying that it takes too long to open the file once, create a data structure in memory with all the information in it, close the file, and then query the data structure?  Or are you saying it would take too long to open the file each time you want to query for word3?

Comment: The file size is huge, so doing a readlines() to get a line and then matching the string for each line in the file would take a long time. I do not want to parse the entire file and have it in a data structure due to memory constraints. File open is not taking much time in my case..

Answer (score 1):

unless the data are ordered in some predictable way (eg sorted) then you *have* to read every line to find the relevant one.

```
with open('/path/file.txt') as input:
    for line in input:
        words = line.split()
        if words and words[0] == 'trigger':
            print words[1:]
            break  # delete this line if you may have multiple matches
```

the above doesn't read the entire file into memory at once (if it is large) - it processes the lines "one by one" (they will be read in buffer sized chunks).

one possible improvement would be if all lines were the same size and very long.  then you could read the start of each line.  but they would have to be *very* long for that to be useful.

if you're on unix then you might find it's quicker to execute a `grep` comand in a subprocess.  but that is still going to scan the entire file (albeit more quickly, in optimized c code).

Answer (score 0):

Python's [linecache](http://docs.python.org/2/library/linecache.html) module is the fastest way I know to look up a given *line number* from a file. You want a line matching the first word in that line, but maybe we can use linecache to get there. So let's create a mapping from words to line numbers:

```
from linecache import getline, getlines
from collections import defaultdict
first_words = defaultdict(int)
first_words.update(
  (line.split()[0], number)
  for number, line in enumerate(getlines(filename), 1)
  if line
)
```

From here, to get a line, just do:

```
>>> getline(filename, first_words['word3'])
'word3 word4 word5\n'
>>> getline(filename, first_words['word4'])
'word4 word6\n'
```

If you try to get a word that wasn't the first word in a line, you'll just get the empty string.

```
>>> getline(filename, first_words['word6'])
''
```

Now, I suppose it's possible you could have the same word beginning some lines, and in that case you might want to get more than one line back. So here's a modified version that accounts for that case:

```
from linecache import getline, getlines
from collections import defaultdict
from operator import itemgetter
first_words = defaultdict(list)
for number, line in enumerate(getlines(filename), 1):
  if line:
    first_words[line.split(0)].append(number)
```

Now to get the lines:

```
itemgetter(*first_words['word3'])(getlines(filename))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using readlines() is really a problem with memory or time. Here is the short example that I have used with a file having *4000* lines each having a minimum of *600* letters in it.

```
import MyUtils as utils
LOGDIR = '/opt/lsf_events/7.0.6/work/blr_ifx/logdir/lsb.acct.1'

utils.Timer.start()
with open(LOGDIR,'r') as fHeader:
for line in fHeader.readlines():
    if '1381671028' in line: #that particular number exists in the last line of the file.
         print line
utils.Timer.end()
```

The Output is...

```
Started Recording Time for the process...
"JOB_FINISH" "7.06" 1381671036 51303 22965 503578626 1 1381671028 0 0 1381671028 "umashank" "batch" "select[ ((type==X64LIN && osrel==50 && clearcase))]" "" "" "blrlc275" "/home/padbgl/spt9_m5p120_5v0_cm112/nodm/default/units/top/simulation/titan/FE/TPL_100_tx_top_new_ls" "" "" "" "1381671028.51303" 0 1 "blrlc275" 64 225.0 "" "/home/padbgl/bin/prjgate -e -- /home/umashank/.lsbatch/blrlc275.21758.0.1381671027.TITAN" 1.037842 0.119981 10116 0 -1 0 0 21997 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 3735 82 -1 "" "padbgl_spt9_m5p120_5v0_cm112" 0 1 "" "" 0 3068 44332 "" "" "" "" 0 "" 0 "" -1 "/umashank" "" "" "" -1 "" "" 5136 "" 1381671028 "" "" 0

Process ended at : 15-10-13 08:02:56 
Total time taken by the process is : 0:00:00.011601
```

Hope you can comfortably use readlines() as it took very less time and is almost instant for a file of memory 3mb.

This is not an alternative for what you asked for, but just trying to tell you that there wont be any damage if you use the typical traditional procedure in reading a file.